# Simple unidirectional flow between two plates with no pressure drop: understanding the meaning of $T_{12}$

Tags: fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics, navier-stokes

Consider the simple problem of a flow between two plates, one at $x_2=0$ and one at $x_2=h$ with the bottom one held stationary and the top plate moving in the $x_1$ direction with velocity $V$. Also, the velocity field is in direction $e_1$: $v(x,y)=v_1(x_2)e_1$ with boundary conditions: $$v_1(0)=0$$ $$v_1(h)=V$$

Assuming no pressure drop in the $x_1$ direction, we obtain from Navier Stokes $$v_1(x_2)=\frac{V}{h}x_2$$

We can now see the stress tensor in matrix form

$$[T]=- \pi \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} + \frac{\mu V}{h} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

So far so good.

**Question:** I can't understand the following sentence, which I found on Gurtin's book:

> The force per unit area exerted by the fluid on the to plate has a tangential shearing component $-\frac{\mu V}{h}$

Indeed my professor drew the following picture (notice the arrow from right to left)

[image]

I think this is because **by definition** the force per unit area exerted by the fluid on the top plate is given by $T (-e_2)= (\frac{-\mu V}{h},\pi,0)$. Now, I see that the first component of this vector is precisely what the book states, i.e  $\frac{- \mu V}{h}$. **Why is the first component referred to the shearing?**

Comment: What particle?..

Comment: Sorry, I meant "on the top plate", I've just fixed it @ChetMiller

Comment: The force per unit area component you are referring to is the force per unit area exerted by the fluid on a plane of constant x2 in the x1 direction.  That is why it is referred to as a shear force.  The second component in the vector is the force per unit area exerted by the fluid on the plane of constant x2 in the x2 direction.  It is a normal force.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks for your comment. I still have a minor question about this: Why do I have to take $-e_2$ as normal direction when I want to compute the stress, and not $e_2$? I mean, if the fluid is pushing to the plate, I'd say the outer normal is $e_2$, not $-e_2$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Cauchy Stress Relationship?  If so, please state it according to your understanding in your own words.

Comment: @ChetMiller I know that $s(-n)=-s(n)$, where $s(n)=Tn$ represents the contact forces applied to a body with outward normal $n$. But I can't see how this helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the force per unit area that the fluid exerts on the plate, the outward normal is directed from the plate to the fluid; that would be -e2.  More, specifically, at a surface S, the force per unit area exerted by the material on side B of the surface on the material on side A of the surface is obtained by drawing a unit normal n from side A to side B, and matrix multiplying this normal by the stress tensor matrix Tn.  The normal is drawn from the side receiving the force to the side exerting the force.

Comment: Thanks @ChetMiller for your answer. Actually, I'd like to understand **why** the normal is drawn from the side receiving the force to the side exerting the force.

Comment: For that, you would have to go back to the derivation of the Cauchy Stress Relationship.  When you are working with the "tensile stress tensor," this is the way it works out.  If you were working with the "compressive stress tensor" (which is opposite in sign to the compressive stress tensor), you with use the normal in the opposite direction.  Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot (Transport Phenomena) uses the compressive stress tensor.

Comment: Okay, so if I set $n = -e_2$, then the *positive part is the inside of the channel*, while the *negative part is the "outside"*. By definition, $s(n)$ gives the force per unit area exerted by the positive part on the negative part, so the force exerted by the fluid on the wall. Right?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes.

Comment: So, conversely, if I want to know the force per unit area exerted by the fluid on the bottom plate I have to compute $s(e_2)$ (evaluated at $x_2=0$, of course), right? @ChetMiller

Comment: No.  You use +e2.  That is the normal from the plate to the fluid.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that $n$ should be $e_2$  if I consider the bottom plate: the positive part is where there's the fluid, while the negative one is the "outside". So the force exerted by the positive on the negative is the one exerted by the fluid on the plate. @ChetMiller

Comment: I'm referring to the bottom plate. Can you confirm my argument?

Comment: The tail of the arrow goes in the part that the force is acting upon.

Comment: Yes,e2.  I thought you had written -e2.

Comment: Probably you read right $-e_2$, but I edited after some seconds with $e_2$. Thanks Chet :-)

Comment: Could you please have a check at my last post, as it's closely related to this question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/637628/shear-stress-for-the-flow-between-two-parallel-plates-with-constant-pressure-gra