# Shear stress for the flow between two parallel plates with constant pressure gradient

Tags: fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, stress-strain, navier-stokes

This is the canonical example, where the velocity $v(x_2)$ is parabolic. Assuming the plates have a distance of $h$, where the bottom one is at $x_2=0$ and the upper plate is at $x_2=h$. Let the viscosity be $\mu$ and let the pressure gradient $\frac{\partial \pi}{\partial x_1} = -\delta$, so that
$$v(x_2)=\frac{\delta x_2}{2  \mu} (h - x_2)$$

Therefore, the non-zero components of the Cauchy stress tensor are $T_{11}=T_{22}=T_{33}= -\pi$ and $T_{12}=T_{21}=\delta (\frac{h}{2} - x_2 )$
since this is

$$[T]=- \pi \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} + \delta (\frac{h}{2} - x_2 )\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

So far so good.

**Question:** my professor wrote in the notes: **shearing forces have opposite direction**, but I am not able to prove this.

---

My attempt:

- Let me be at the upper plate. To compute the force, per unit area, acting on the plate by the fluid, I need to consider as normal $-e_2$, and hence I obtain $$T(-e_2)=(-\delta(\frac{h}{2} - h),+\pi,0)$$
  and the first component is **positive**. (I evaluated at $x_2=h$)
- Let's consider now the lower plate: There we need to consider as normal $e_2$, and so $$T e_2=(\delta(\frac{h}{2} - 0),-\pi,0)$$
  **but as you can see the first component is still positive!!!**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything.  The shear force exerted by the fluid on the plate is in the positive e1 direction at both the upper plate and the lower plate.  I have no idea what your professor meant by his statement, except possibly that the shearing force exerted by the fluid on a plate is in the opposite direction of the shearing force exerted by the plate on the fluid.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chet. However, it seems that the other answer to my post is saying that I'm wrong and the two stresses from the fluid to the wall have opposite direction, right? @ChetMiller

Comment: I stand by what I said.  I have tons of experience with such flows.

Comment: I didn't mean to object to your kind answer, with whom I agree. I was only asking if what Chemomechanics means in his answer is the same thing you mean. I didn't want to sound rude, I'm sorry

Comment: I mean, if I look at his first image, it seems the two stresses have opposite direction, which Is wrong in this case...

Comment: In this flow, the axial velocity varies with x2, so the flow is non-homogeneous.  Thus, that image can not apply across the entire flow field.  The symmetry of the system should tell you immediately that the shear forces of the fluid on the two plates are in the same direction.  If you flipped the channel upside down, it would look exactly the same.

Comment: For this flow, the picture in the figure only applies locally over differential distances in x2.

Comment: Your previous consideration about symmetry is really useful, thanks. However, when you say: "the picture in the figure only applies locally over differential distances in x2", what do you mean? I'm really sorry but I don't get this point @ChetMiller

Comment: The figure shows the x1/x2 shear stresses on the four sides of a differential element of fluid with sides dx1 and dx2.  On the larger scale in x2, this shear stress varies with x2.  It is actually zero at the centerline of the channel, and actually changes sign between the upper half and lower half of the channel.

Comment: Thanks so much! One last thing, before accepting your answer. What is the physical meaning of the fact that the shear stress $T_{12}$ changes sign when moving from the upper plate to the lower plate ?

Comment: The velocity gradient at the centerline is zero.  The maximum velocity occurs at the centerline of the channel.  This is where the shear stress is zero.  The upper and lower walls exert shear stresses in the negative x1 direction of the fluid, and hold it back; this is balanced by the forward force of the pressure gradient on the fluid.

Comment: I think I got it: *"The upper and lower walls exert shear stresses in the negative x1 direction of the fluid"* refers to the force exterted by the wall on the fluid, while when you say *"the forward force of the pressure gradient on the fluid"* you mean the force exerted by the fluid on the plates, which is in positive $e_1$ direction, right? @ChetMiller

Comment: No.  The pressure gradient is acting on the back end and front end of the fluid in the e1 direction, and this is pushing it forward against the drag on the fluid from the upper and lower plates.  The pressure gradient has nothing to do with the pressure force on the plates.

Comment: The overall force balance is $(P_1-P_2)wh=2\tau_{12} wL$ where w is the depth into the e3 direction

Comment: I think I finally understood the idea, even if I still can't understand what physically represent the $\frac{\partial \pi}{\partial x_1} = - \delta$ assumption. In particular, what represents the $-$ sign? @ChetMiller

Comment: Converting the notation that I used in my previous post, the overall force balance reads $\frac{(P_2-P_1)}{L}=\frac{d\pi}{dx_1}=-\delta=2\frac{T_{12}}{h}$ where $T_{12}$ is the shear stress exerted by each wall on the fluid.  $\delta$ is defined as minus the pressure gradient.

Comment: Thanks Chet. I also thought I could see this way: $\nabla \pi= [-\delta,0]$ so this means the the pressure is directed also from right to left, with no $x_2$ component.

Comment: By the way, $T_{12}$ is also the shear stress exerted by the fluid on the wall, right? @ChetMiller Since $T_{12}=T_{21}$

Comment: The shear stress exerted by the fluid on the wall is in the positive e1 direction, and is equal to $-T_{12}=-T_{21}=\frac{2\delta}{h}$

Comment: Okay, because $T_{12}$ means "normal to plane $e_1$" and "direction of traction $e_2$", so indeed I have that the positive part is the fluid and the negative is the lower plate. So indeed $-T_{12}$ is, by action/reaction, the shear exerted by the wall on the fluid. I finally got it, right? @ChetMiller

Comment: I think you did.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: my professor wrote in the notes: shearing forces have opposite direction, but I am not able to prove this.

It's possible that your professor simply meant that a state of (positive or negative) shear stress requires four forces in different directions to maintain equilibrium; note that any pair of forces acting in the same axis point in opposite directions:

[image]

(images from [my website](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/generalized%20Hooke%27s%20Law.htm))

Elimination of any of these forces would result in rotational and translation acceleration:

[image]

Comment: I see your point, but as you can see from my computations I obtain the same direction. So the question is: why is that? What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You’re comparing shear forces at the upper and lower plates; I’m comparing shear forces on either side of a *differential element* anywhere shear exists. The squares above do not show your channel or tube!

Comment: Okay, so you agree with the fact that the shearing forces applied by the fluid on the plates are both in the positive $e_1$ direction? @Chemomechanics

Comment: Of course; symmetry requires this as well.