# Is there one or two forces acting on a plate in a fluid?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics

In my Fluids Dynamics course, we have the following two examples
[image]

[image]

What I don't understand is: Why is it that in the first example we only calculated one shear stress force while in the second example we have two shear stress forces?

Comment: Flow over a plate, by default, typically means flow on one side of the plate only. In contrast, pulling a plate through a fluid involves flow over both sides, and the diagram confirms this. Is this what you’re asking about?

Comment: @Chemomechanics Yes, I don't understand how in the first question there is flow on one side of the plate. I mean when y is varied wouldnt there be second flow?

Comment: Y is _not_ varied, as in the plate is not moved upward. The velocity is a function of height and that’s it.

Comment: @josephh, is the plate static or is it moving forward?

Comment: @josephh, what I am confused about is that shear stress = force(F)/area(A). In the first question what is A the area of? And if there is an area what is under it? a second flow?

Comment: I mean since the plate is not moving upward and the shear stress depends on area, what is this area moving upward to y=0.15?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean. Think about the fluid as being divided up into many layers. One layer of fluid is moving faster than the layer below it due due friction between each layer. The question is simply asking you to calculate the shear stress at a certain height. Note that $\frac{du}{dy}$ = rate of shear deformation (shear velocity). Thanks.

Comment: @josephh, what I mean is that "shear stress at a certain height" is tangential force per area. What is this area of?   Also, can I think of each layer of the fluid as a moving plate?

Comment: I think the fact that the word "plate" being used in both questions has caused most of the confusion. Ignore this word in the first question since there is no "plate" as in the second question, so you need not consider an area as you do in question one. Make sense? Also, have a read of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) since there is an example and explanations of what's happening. Cheers.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/637673/146039). A state of shear stress requires upper and lower *forces*, but these are integral to the stress state and can’t be decoupled. This is different from a plate having upper and lower *surfaces*, each exposed to a shear stress. Does this start to clarify the situation? If so, I’ll convert it a more complete answer.

Comment: @Chemomechanics yes please explain the difference. It would be really useful too me and help me understand this course. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it seems like the confusion might arise from the difference between forces and stresses; the difference between a stress state at a point, a stress existing at a surface, and the corresponding force applied to that surface; and the number of forces that produce a stress state and how to count and distinguish them. Is that roughly the case? If so, it might be helpful to review some points to check where the confusion arises.

1. A stress can broadly be thought of as a force per unit area.
2. If the force points toward the area, the stress is a normal stress; otherwise, it is a shear stress.
3. Thus, for a surface (the surface of a horizontal plate, for example), we can have three stresses, composing a general stress state: a normal stress from a force pointing up or down, a shear stress from a force pointing in and out of the page, and a shear stress from a force pointing left or right. (For this problem, only the last is relevant.)
4. For this surface, there's a one-to-one relationship between the stress and a single force. If we know that the surface of a plate is subjected to a shear stress (from fluid flow, for example), then it's subjected to a single parallel—or traction—force, and vice versa.
5. Points in a region are different. We can imagine a point as the infinitesimal limit of a very small 3D cube. At equilibrium, we need equal opposing forces on that cube, or it would start to accelerate. As a simple example, any upward force must be paired with a downward force to produce a normal—or axial—stress state. One (normal) stress state, but two forces that together impart that stress.
6. For a shear stress state at a point, we need fully four forces to prevent translational and rotational acceleration of the infinitesimal cube. **One (shear) stress state, four forces:**
   [image]

   [image]
7. In the two questions you show above, the first is asking about a stress state at a point, and the second is asking about the total force on a plate. That's why we obtain a single answer in the first case even though pairs of forces are acting at that point, as you note. In the second case, there are spatially distinct shear stresses acting at the top and bottom of the plate. Each shear stress is associated with balanced pairs of forces as discussed in point 6, but only one force for each is applied to the plate surface, as discussed in point 3. We take these two forces and add them to obtain the total associated load on the plate.
8. Note some fundamental differences between the two cases: In the first case, the single shear stress (if decomposed into forces acting on a fluid element) consists of forces pointing in opposite directions as shown in the animation above. Nothing is pulling the water. In the second case, the forces on the plate are pointing in the same direction. One force comes from a shear stress on the top, and one comes from a different shear stress on the bottom. (Only in the symmetric case are they equal.) These two forces are balanced by a third force pulling the plate. Finally, the first problem asks for a shear stress magnitude, whereas the second problem asks for a net drag force.
9. Moving forward, it would be good to avoid terms such as "shear stress force" to avoid confusion. A stress state can exist at a point; an associated force can be applied to that point. It's best not to conflate the two, or you might conclude that a shear stress = two "shear stress forces" = two shear stresses that should be added together. This would be incorrect.
10. As an aside, note that the plate is not under simple shear. It is under a complex stress state (that varies across the plate) arising from the two traction forces on the top and bottom and the axial load pulling it forward. Analysis of the stress state in the plate is beyond the scope of these questions.

Do these points make sense?

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. But If we divide the fluid into horizontal layers moving to the right and then consider one of the layers in the middle. Suppose this layer is moving at a speed V, then there is a force moving this layer. So we can think about this layer as a second horizontal plate moving in the middle of the fluid. Hence there is two shear stress forces acting on the horizontal layers above and under this plate just like in the second example. Could you please tell me why this is wrong?

Comment: It’s wrong because in the first case, the forces are pointing in opposite directions, as in the animation above, composing a single shear stress. Nothing is pulling the water. In the second problem, the forces on the plate are pointing in the same direction. One force comes from a shear stress on the top, and one comes from a different shear stress on the bottom. These two forces are balanced by a third force pulling the plate. Thus, the two cases can’t be considered equivalent.

Comment: So basically in the first question there is one stress state while in the second question there are two stress states. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that’s a good way of thinking of it.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of sheer stress on a surface with flow on only one side:

1. Fluid flowing inside a pipe (and if you want a flat surface then make the pipe rectangular). The surface is the wall of the pipe.
2. Force on the bed of a river owing to the water flow (and if you want a flat bed then make it a man-made canal with a flat bottom). The surface is the river bed.
3. etc.

In these examples, if the fluid is flowing to the right then the sheer stress on the boundary owing to viscosity of the fluid is in the direction to the right. Assuming the boundary (e.g. the pipe or river bed) is not moving then there is another force acting on it, directed to the left, from whatever other objects it is connected to. In this example the other force would typically be stress forces in the solid materials which are ultimately connected to the ground of planet Earth.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is: If we think about the layer of the fluid which is moving at speed $u(0.15)$. Aren't there two shear stress forces acting on it from the layers of fluid above and under it? Why are we considering only the stress force from above?

Comment: @gbd I added a paragraph to deal with this.

Comment: @AndrewSteane You may be interested in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/696452/phase-velocity-of-matter-wave-from-the-perspective-of-special-relativity) question regarding a query from your book on relativity.