# Intuitive explanation of why for a Newtonian fluid, the shear stress on a face of a cubic element depends on two velocity derivatives and not one

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I drew a image below. For that face, of normal $y$, we have that the shear stress acting on the $x$ direction is:

$$ \tau_{yx} = \mu(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x})$$

with $\mu$ the viscosity, $u$ the along-$x$ velocity, and $v$ the along-$y$ velocity. Now, I understand that a gradient in $u$ velocity in $y$ creates a $ \tau_{xy}   $, i.e a shear in $y$.  But I do not understand how is that shear a function of $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, which in my mind should only give a shear on faces of normal $x$. I do know that for rotational equilibrium shear stresses are symmetric, so that $ \tau_{xy} = \tau_{yx} $. But this to me does not explain conceptually why $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ is giving a shear on a surface of normal $y$. Can you please provide an explanation? Similar question can be made for each of the other faces, of course.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there one or two forces acting on a plate in a fluid?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/696254/is-there-one-or-two-forces-acting-on-a-plate-in-a-fluid)

Comment: Completely unrelated sorry, please read my question again and check my drawing.

Comment: So that the assumptions and context are clear, what’s the reference for the shear stress equation?

Comment: Are you familiar with the extension of Newton's Law of Viscosity to a tenurially correct 3D version?  If not, see Transport Phenomena, by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Chapter 1.

Comment: StackExchange suggests me the [following question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187044/in-a-fluid-why-are-the-shear-stresses-tau-xy-and-tau-yx-equal) in the right column : "In a fluid, where are the shear stress $\tau_{xy}$ and $\tau_{yx}$ equal ?" You might find something there. It is related to the angular acceleration of the fluid particle that is considered. The two components must be equal for the angular acceleration to stay finite.

Comment: I know that the two shear stresses are equal. That is not what I am asking. I am asking for a physical explanation of why ∂v/∂x is giving an along-x shear on a surface of normal y. If you are on the face of normal y, I intuitively expect the shear in the x direction to be determined ONLY by  ∂u/∂y. Just imagine creating a shear with your hand on a pile of paper sheets, that makes physical sense. How do you physically explain ∂v/∂x giving an along-x shear on a surface of normal y?